# CSS line-height is fubar on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I have a div containing some text with individual letters having a background/border effect as illustrated in the screenshot:

[image]

Both the parent div and the individual numbers have a line-height of 1. See CSS below:

```
.jobcount {
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1 !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    b {
        line-height: 1;
        padding: 3px 4px 2px 4px;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background: #A4CD39;
        position: relative;
        color: #016699;

        &:before {
            opacity: 0.2;
            border-top: 1px solid #016699;
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }
}
```

On both mobile iOS and Android (less pronounced on Android, but still present) there is additional space below the numbers, causing the background to extend below where it is desired. For an example of how it should appear (and does on all 4 desktop browsers), see:

[image]

What am I missing on mobile browsers that is causing line height to differ?

Comment: Can you tell whether the text would display properly without the numbers? If so, try adding a height constraint to the numbers in addition to the line-height and hide the overflow.

Comment: I tried changing one of the numbers to an uppercase letter and a lowercase letter. No change.

Comment: I don't mean changing the numbers to another character, but rather removing the `<b>` tags completely to see if they're causing the issue.

Comment: If I remove the <b> tag elements entirely, the line height stops at the bottom of the 'g' in right now, as I would expect it to.

Comment: You should post code (HTML and CSS) that reproduces the issue. Preferably use CSS and not some language to be transformed to CSS, but if you use the latter, please state that clearly. If you think the problem is in differing line height, please state how you inferred that and what line height of which element(s) you are referring to.

Comment: OK, so it's definitely the `<b>` tags at-fault. Does it help at all setting the `<b>` tags to `height: 1em;` as well?

Comment: Actually, it was the font-face I was using. Tried removing it and using arial/helvetical only and the spacing was appropriate. Now to find out why this font face is messed up (Avenir from myfonts.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many bold fonts do have slightly different metrics than their non-bold counterparts. So one solution would be to find a font where the heights are identical for bold.

Or indeed, as David Millar mentioned in the comments, assign a height to the `b` element. If you do, make sure that you also give it `display:inline-block` or the height will be ignored.

Comment: This ended up being an issue with the vertical baseline being different between mac and windows fonts. There are some steps that can be taken to normalize this, but the issue remains with the font file itself. I ended up choosing a more standard font for this particular widget to avoid any issues.